# Difference between using ころ and ころに？

Tags: grammar

I'm kinda new to this site so I'm not entirely sure how the format works.

In the sentence below, which I'm assuming I translated correctly as "When I was in high school, I studied often":

> 高校のころ、僕は勉強した。

some people tend to add に after ころ when I looked it up. Is it necessary and is it wrong to have/not have the に particle in the sentence? I'm fairly certain that the に particle is used for destination/certain time reference among other things but I don't see why it's more common to not have it at the end of ころ while some people actually do

Also, I didn't know if I can include a separate question since I didn't really want to make a whole new thread for it but is it wrong if I were to say「高校でいるのころ」 instead of 「高校のころ」 to be more specific?

Comment: One thought: に is a lot more than just a particle for "destination" or for "certain time reference" so don't use that to define all of its sues.

Comment: Second thought: it would be wrong to say 「高校でいる**の**ころ」. Because you don't use の to connect verbs used to describe nouns. (連体)

Comment: Either will do, having or not having に.

Comment: so that means that 高校でいていた頃 would be a fine translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the translation, I would say

> 高校のころ、僕はよく勉強していた。 (spoken)
>
> 僕が高校生だった頃はよく勉強していた。 (written)

- You usually use 高校のころ when you're speaking.
- よく勉強していた: Here, よく勉強する means study often, 勉強 has a duration so していた is better.
- After 頃 , you usually use は or nothing.

You can use 頃に when you want to insist on the time context. Like:

> あの頃にあなたに会った。 (It's あの頃 that I met you)

or when it's the destination.

> あの頃に戻りたい。 (I want to go back to あの頃)

Comment: totally forgot to add the よく there lol.　I didn't know there was such a large difference between spoken and written sentences. This language just got a whole lot harder haha. It makes sense now thanks

Comment: The last part is kinda irrelevant.

Comment: Which part do you mean?